# Combining empty() and trim() kills Apache server

Tags: php, apache

I want to trim a string and then check said string for being empty, like so:

```
if(!empty(trim($string))) { ... }
```

But for some unknown reason this happens to make my local Apache crash. The only error message I get states that Apache stopped working. My Apache version is

> Apache/2.4.2 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.4

The following code though executes perfectly:

```
 $string = trim($string);
 if(!empty($string)) { ... }
```

So, my code is running just fine. Still I was wondering: why does Apache crash because of this? In my eyes, both code snippets are the same. Or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you're running PHP 5.5 already:

> Prior to PHP 5.5, empty() only supports variables; anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)). Instead, use trim($name) == false.

(quoting from the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php))

Answer (score 0):

There is **absolutely no point** in running such a code.

One don't need it at all. `trim()` always returns a value - so, no special `empty()` feature ever be used.

```
if(trim($string)) { ... }
// or, better yet
if($string = trim($string)) { ... }
```

would be more than enough.

Comment: I am sorry but empty() can also return true if there is in fact a value present.
`The following things are considered to be empty:

"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
$var; (a variable declared, but without a value)`

empty(" 0") would return false, while empty("0") would return true.

Comment: Don't be too sorry - there is no reason for that. Provided code will act **exactly the same way**